# Composite primary key with sequelize-typescript and node-sqlite3

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript, node-sqlite3

How can i create the following composite primary key (using sqlite) with `sequelize-typescript`?

```
CREATE TABLE files(
   `hash` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   `filePath` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   PRIMARY KEY(hash, filePath)
);
```

The following fails when trying to insert a `hash` for the second time:

```
@Table({
    tableName: 'files'
})
class File extends Model {
  
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column({
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false,
    })
    hash!: string
    
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column({
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false,
    })
    filePath!: string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out i had to remove both `unique: true,` statements. Now, the sql and behaviour are as expected.